# Updating input's ngmodel variable with initial value from within - HTML only solution?

Tags: angular, typescript

Does anyone know how to set initial value of `"1"` to `"some"` variable during init using ngModel? 
*Update: I am wondering how to do it in HTML only

**component.html** :

```html
<input type="text" value="1" name="some" [(ngModel)]="some"/>
<p>{{some}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your class is implementing `OnInit`, then assigning would be better to be done in `ngOnInit()`. In your case it would be like.

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit{
  some: any;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.some = 1;
  }
}
```

Or if you are not implementing `OnInit` then it would be better to do assigning in constructor as @German Quinteros suggested in his answere. In your case it would be like.

```
   export class ExampleComponent{
      some: any;
      constructor(){
        this.some = 1;
      }
    }
```

Or you can directly assign a value to the variable at the time of declaration like ,

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit{
      some: any = 1;
      ngOnInit(){

      }
    }
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I was wondering if this can be done without touching typescript and performed in HTML only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the constructor (`.component.ts`) of your Component:

```
export class MyComponent {
   some: string;
   constructor () {
     this.some = "1";
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I am still trying to figure out how to do that in HTML only :(

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the HTML?
If you use ```[(ngModel)]="some"``` it always going to get the value from ```some``` and will save the value tip in the input in ```some```.
And that is something nice because then if you want to save that value from the ```input``` when the user click a button, you would only need to get the value from the ```some``` property, instead of extract the value from the input.

Comment: Let's say there is some data that is generated in HTML only and you want to render HTML generated value back to the component and use that later in TS. That HTML value is outside component's typescript, but want to bring it in after. Hope I answered the question :)